# Shell script to deploye plsql packages ||Sqlplus: command not found error

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix

I have created the following shell script for deploying all the packages and tables scripts mentioned below.
I first entered teh directry by :

```
cd /home/test
```

Then i called my shell script sh `XXHCM_OBJECT.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/sh 

# Parameters to be accepted from command prompt
# Parameter 1 = Apps username/Password
# Parameter 2 = BOLINF username/Password
# Parameter 3 = Host name for the instance
# Parameter 4 = Port Number for the instance
# Parameter 5 = DB Name for the instance


#APPS_USER="$1"
#BOLINF_USER="$2"
#HOST_NAME="$3"
#PORT_NUMBER="$4"
#DB_NAME="$5"

LOGFILE="$CUST_TOP/XXHCM_OBJECTS.log"

#APPS_USERNAME=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "1" -d /)
#APPS_PWD=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "2" -d /)

#-
#-  reading program parameters
#-

echo "Enter APPS User: "

read APPS

echo "Enter APPS Password: "

stty -echo

read APPS_PWD

stty echo


echo "Enter Custom User: "

read CUSTOM

echo "Enter Custom Password: "

stty -echo

read CUSTOM_PWD

stty echo

echo "Enter Install Server (SID): "

read SID



APPS_USER="$APPS/$APPS_PWD@$SID"

CUSTOM_USER="$CUSTOM/$CUSTOM_PWD@$SID"


APPS_USERNAME=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "1" -d /)

APPS_PWD=$(echo $APPS_USER|cut -f "2" -d /)

echo "" > $LOGFILE


echo "" > $LOGFILE
echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..."
echo "Starting installation of XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS ..." >>$LOGFILE
echo "" >>$LOGFILE

echo "" >>$LOGFILE
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..."
echo "Copying Files To Appropriate Directories ..." >>$LOGFILE
echo "" >>$LOGFILE


echo "Changing permissions ... " >> $LOGFILE
chmod 777 *.*
echo "Changed permissions ... " >> $LOGFILE

echo "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants...">>$LOGFILE
echo "Creating Custom Package, Synonyms and Grants..."
echo "">>$LOGFILE


if sqlplus $APPS_USER @XXHCM_MAPPING_STG.sql
then
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" 
fi
if sqlplus $APPS_USER @XXdiv_ASSIGNMENT_SUPERVISOR_STG.sql
then
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Insert data into entities table in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Error in Insert data into entities table in APPS schema" 
fi
if sqlplus $APPS_USER @XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I.pks
then
    echo "Package specification for package XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I created in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Package specification for package XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I created in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in creating Package specification" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Package specification" 
fi

if sqlplus $APPS_USER @XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I.pkb
then
    echo "Package body created for package XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I in APPS schema" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Package body created for package XXHCM_STAGING_TO_I in APPS schema"
else
    echo "Error in creating Package body" >> $LOGFILE
    echo "Error in creating Package body" 
fi
echo "">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully">>$LOGFILE
echo "Package, Synonyms,grants and Tables created successfully"
echo "">>$LOGFILE


echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS"
echo "Installation completed for XXHCM_OBJECTS - XXHCM_OBJECTS" >> $LOGFILE
# *****************************************************************************
# End of Script
# *****************************************************************************
```

But at the output it is giving me an error :

```
sqlplus: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the sqlplus installation location in your PATH. Suppose your Oracle installation is on `/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1` , sqlplus should be on `/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin` , all you need to do is add to your script something like :

```
export PATH=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin:$PATH
```

or like it is usually done, export a ORACLE_HOME variable and add it to the PATH, like

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: @sasteck- I should add this in my script ?

Comment: How will i find my correct Oracle installation is on /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1

Comment: @sasteck- I did add this in my script. But still got the same error

Comment: This was just an example, I'm assuming you have a client or a database installation on this server? What is the full path from where you call sqlplus ? Or you have never executed sqlplus in there before ?

Comment: @sasteck- I havent executed the sqlplus. Infact new to shell script itself

Comment: I executed  env | grep ORACLE_HOME
and got output as ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1

Comment: I see.. check if the file /etc/oratab exists on your server, there should point to your home.. you can also do something like `find / -name 'sqlplus' -print 2>/dev/null` to see If there is any sqlplus installed. otherwise you may need to install it. sqlplus is part of a client or database installation, and does not come by default with linux

Comment: I got an output for  find / -name 'sqlplus' -print 2>/dev/null

Comment: -bash: /etc/oratab: Permission denied